# Does the SSIS Package fail ,when one of the container failed

Tags: sql-server, events, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a package with 1 container.Does the ssis pacakge fail,If that container fail!?
The property

> FAIL PACKAGE ON FAILURE
>   is false for the container.

Does that mean the package fail only if this property set to TRUE,other wise only the container status is failed ,and the package status is not !?

Comment: yes it will fail unless the MaximumErrorCount is raised to 2 or more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If the Sequence Container fails, the overall package will fail.  Raise the `MaximiumAllowedErrors` property of the Sequence Container to get the behavior you want.

### Example

Below we have an example package.  The Sequence Container has a task that will never succeed.

[image]

Above, the Sequence Container has failed and the Package has failed. Below are the properties of the container above.  These are the default values for a new container.

[image]

Now lets stop and study. If we compare the package behavior against the property settings, this looks wrong.  Here we have set `FailPackageOnFailure=False`, yet a Sequence Container failure is causing a Package failure.  Why is this?  Unintuitive attribute names. See [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/381681/ssis100-failparentonfailure-failpackageonfailure-are-erroneously-regarded-to-be-always-true) Microsoft Connect issue.  You are not alone in your confusion. The official explanation from Microsoft is this.

> Despite some pretty circular previous messages, we believe that the
>   feature is behaving as designed. When you set FailParentOnFailure to
>   false, the parent will not fail until the number of failures in the
>   child exceeds the MaximumAllowedErrors threshold. When you set
>   FailparentOnFailure to true, the parent will fail on the first
>   occurence of an error regardless of the MaximiumAllowedErrors
>   threshold.

The important piece of information to take away from that quote is that the `FailPackageOnFailure` and `MaximiumAllowedErrors` work as a pair!!!

So - knowing this - we can achieve the expected behavior by raising the `MaximiumAllowedErrors` count from 1 to 2.

[image]

This will allow you to have a sequence container which fails, but does NOT fail the overall package.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how the package and containers is set up. You have to open/import it (in SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio) and run on preferable test data to see which one fails. Do the two containers have inter-dependencies on each other?

Comment: sorry,my question was deos package fail ,when one of the containers failed.There are no interdependencies between the containers

Comment: How is the constrains between the containers set up: On completion or on Success

Comment: On on completion it will go to the next container if  on success it will fail and end

Comment: ok.Let us consider my package has only one container.If the container failed then the package status aslos failed?

Comment: but,    by default FAIL PACKAGE ON FAILURE is false for the container.