# SSIS container properties

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

Really need your suggestion, I tried to fail the Loop Container to make process go to the Failure path due to failed in data flow (Sequence Container). I am not sure how to setup the container properties, normally I use default value. Thank you

**Control Flow**

[image]

**Loop Container Property**

[image]

**Sequence Container Property**
[image]

Comment: Set the dataflow task to fail parent on failure to true.  This would normally work that way by default, but it doesn't when you force the execution result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `FailParentOnFailure` property of the Data Flow task.

See this guide/answers:

- [Does the SSIS Package fail ,when one of the container failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40893381/1008588)
- [DtsContainer.FailParentOnFailure Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtscontainer.failparentonfailure?view=sqlserver-2019)